# Devise custom registrations controller error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When I try to create a custom devise controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    # add custom create logic here
  end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```

I get a following error:

Unknown action

AbstractController::ActionNotFound

It is not the problem with routes. I tried to inherit RegistrationsController from ApplicationController and it works fine. As soon as i try to inherit from Devise::RegistrationsController it shows an error. It can't be an action problem to, becuse I tried to create a different action, and I get the same error.

```
# app/config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
root :to => "registrations#new"
```

Using Rails 3.0.4

Comment: did you try to add respond_to block?

Answer (score 3):

In your routes you have to use devise_scope if you are overriding devise default actions.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
devise_scope :user do
    root :to => "registrations#new"
end
```

For a similar issue please see http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/a5beaaf4b1ad343a

Also here are the docs on changing default sign in routes, I know this you are doing registration, but this could be similar: [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes)

Comment: Thanks, I will check out that

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code in my project successfully:

```
app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
end

routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" }
```

Comment: I guess this is the case when you are using users namespace.

Comment: I had same problem with namespaces.